# jQuery vertical animated bar tutorial

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate

I'm not sure if I can ask this here - but I've been trying to find a tutorial for a **single** animated bar, done in jquery/svg (probably with .animate, i think).

I'm not trying to find a loading bar, I just want a bar that actually shows - for example - a 0 degrees to 24 degrees Celsius visualization.

I can't visualize how to actually do it, and I can't actually find a tutorial on it either. Can anyone point me to a tutorial (or clear cut tips, I know you guys emphasize individual hard work here, and I want to learn as well) that I can actually understand how to do it?

here's a rough visualization :

```
0 Deg                          24 Deg
******                          ____
******                          |  |
******                          |  |
******                          |  |
______      animates to        _|__|_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a html/css problem or javascript/jquery?
Small sample that demonstrates one possible way to do this:

```
<button id="start">start animation</button>
<div id="foo"></div>

#foo {
    background-color: rgb(235,235,235);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgb(130,130,130);
    width: 20px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}

$(function() {
    $('#start').click(function() {
        $('#foo').animate({
            height: 200,
            top: 0
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfX8R/)

Comment: wow that's what I exactly wanted. hmm, I couldn't actually visualize the height being 0 px at the start... now I know you'll just need to define 0px as the starting height, then animate it upwards by height.

Comment: the numbers counting towards the desired degrees should be manageable, I'll just do a count+1 till [desirednumber] in jquery if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Just set up a ratio like 1 degree equals 10px. If you want to go from 0 degree (0px height) to 10 degree (100px) let the animate function do the work.